# how to install libuhd-dev uhd-host python3-uhd on windows?

Tags: python, windows, ubuntu

I'm trying to try running a script on my widows10 computer
here's the script :
https://github.com/RUB-SysSec/DroneSecurity

I am trying to run `./src/droneid_receiver_live.py` and I need to `sudo apt install libuhd-dev uhd-host python3-uhd` but this command is linux based and I tried `wsl --install virtual ubuntu server` to run the script, everything works until I run the `droneid_receiver_live.py` script, the loading takes forever and I waited 2hr for nothing to happen. So I went back to windows command to install the package from the ways below :

```
choco install packageName libuhd-dev uhd-host python3-uhd
winget install libuhd-dev uhd-host python3-uhd
```

RESULTS:

```
No package found matching input criteria.
Package not found: libuhd-dev
No package found matching input criteria.
Package not found: uhd-host
No package found matching input criteria.
Package not found: python3-uhd
```

Does anyone know how to install this on windows or why is my windows (UBUNTU) takes forever to load when running that script?